# Axios post request not sending data or recieving response

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, authentication

This is my first time trying to do basic authentication and nothing seems to be working. Axios post is not sending data/controllers not returning a response. I cant find exactly where I am going wrong, but I am wondering if the body of my http post request has to match requestbody or what I need to change to get userrepositroy to save form dat in database?

```
const Login = () => {

    const [registration, setRegistration] = useState("true");

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [regPwd, setRegPwd] = useState("");
    const [regUsername, setRegUsername] = useState("");

    const [logUsername, setLogUsername] = useState("");
    const [logPwd, setLogPwd] = useState("");

    const redirect = useNavigate();

    const handleRegSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const registerDTO = {
            email: email,
            username: regUsername,
            password: regPwd
        }
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/registration',
                 {registerDTO} )
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    redirect("/user/${username}")
                } else {
                    setEmail("")
                    setRegUsername("")
                    setRegPwd("")
                }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const handleLogSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const logUser = {
            username: logUsername,
            password: logPwd
        }
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login',
                { logUser })
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    redirect("/user/${username}")
                } else {
                    setLogUsername("")
                    setLogPwd("")
                }
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        };   
    }




Spring boot



@CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

       
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> processRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid RegisterDTO registerDTO,
                                                      BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("An error occurred!");
        }

        User existingUser = userRepository.findByUsername(registerDTO.getUsername());

        if (existingUser != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username already exists!");
        }


        User user = new User(registerDTO.getEmail(), registerDTO.getUsername(), registerDTO.getPassword());
        userRepository.save(user);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> processLogin(@RequestBody @Valid LoginDTO loginDTO,
                                               BindingResult bindingResult,HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("An error occurred!");
        }

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(loginDTO.getUsername());

        if (user == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Username does not exist!");
        }

        String password = loginDTO.getPassword();

        if (!user.isMatchingPassword(password)) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Invalid password!");
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're sending to `http://localhost:8080/registration` but defined the route as `localhost:8080/register`